# Passing an Argument to page template WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a page tamplate "products"

```
<?php

/*
 * Template Name: products
 * Description: A Page Template.
 */

?>
```

I want to pass an argument from Single.php  to the page template (products), So for that I create a funtion to filter `query_vars` :

```
function add_custom_query_var( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "prod";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var' );
```

then I write this url in my Single page (single.php)

```
<a href="<?php echo add_query_arg( 'prod', "my_arg", site_url( '/products/' ) )?>"> test link </a>
```

but I get Not Found URL.

Any advice ?? Thanks.

Comment: Have you created the page "products", following the: Pages -> New Page? And select from the sidebar the products template in the section when you create the page.

Comment: Yes, I created the page "products", and I selected the products template  :D

Comment: Can you paste the URL from your page here?, thanks.

Comment: This is URL : `http://localhost/shopping/products/?prod=my_arg`

Comment: That seems like the URL from the link, I mean the URL from the page you have created. Try to access to http://localhost/shopping/products/ if you can see the content of your page or anything different from 'Not Found' then you have a problem with the URL from the original page.